# Elasticsearch top_hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have to get top N documents from multiple indices, then group the resulting set by index. I've tried the following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "some term"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      },
      "aggs": {
          "top_results": {
              "top_hits": {
                  "size": 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It aggregates results by `_index` and then limits each group to N (20) documents. But I need to receive no more than 20 documents in total.